Python Azure: ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2427)
I have the following Flask app code:
def do_binance_trading(queue): 
    print("Going to start a socket. . .")
    socket_manager = BinanceSocketManager.getInstance() 
    socket_manager.startSocket(queue) 
    print("Socket started. . .")

@app.route("/") 
def main(): 
global process
global queue
global latestQueueData print("Ping app. . .")
if process is not None and process.is_alive():
    print("App is running. Trading process id:" + str(process.pid))    
    # Retrieve all data from the queue
    queue_data = []
    while not queue.empty():
        queue_data.append(queue.get())

    if len(queue_data) > 0 and latestQueueData != queue_data[-1]:
        latestQueueData = queue_data[-1]

    # Display all data in the queue
    return latestQueueData.replace("\n", "<br>"), 200
else:
    print("Starting App. . .")
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_binance_trading, args=(queue,))
    process.start()
    print("Process started. . .")
    return "Trading started", 200

if name == "main": 
    app.run()

The app is deployed to Azure Web Service. The logic is pretty much simple:

Run the app. The Process starts
On root refresh - get the stats from the queue for the process.

App is in general working fine, but from time to time, without any influence or logic, the process dies and I got the following Azure log trace:
2024-04-27T09:59:19.988977259Z Process Process-14:
2024-04-27T09:59:19.990693175Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991752385Z   File "/opt/python/3.11.7/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in \_bootstrap
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991789786Z     self.run()
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991796086Z   File "/opt/python/3.11.7/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991800386Z     self.\_target(\*self.\_args, \*\*self.\_kwargs)
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991824686Z   File "/tmp/8dc60406808a4da/app.py", line 29, in do_binance_trading
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991829486Z     socket_manager.startSocket(queue)
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991832986Z   File "/tmp/8dc60406808a4da/data/binance_data_socket.py", line 73, in startSocket
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991837086Z     rel.dispatch()
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991840786Z   File "/tmp/8dc60406808a4da/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rel/rel.py", line 228, in dispatch
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991844886Z     registrar.dispatch()
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991849086Z   File "/tmp/8dc60406808a4da/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rel/registrar.py", line 126, in dispatch
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991852986Z     if not self.loop():
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991857186Z            ^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991861086Z   File "/tmp/8dc60406808a4da/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rel/registrar.py", line 135, in loop
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991864786Z     e = self.check_events()
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991868786Z         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991872386Z   File "/tmp/8dc60406808a4da/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rel/registrar.py", line 300, in check_events
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991876686Z     self.handle_error(fd)
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991880286Z   File "/tmp/8dc60406808a4da/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rel/registrar.py", line 185, in handle_error
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991884187Z     self.callback('read', fd)
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991888087Z   File "/tmp/8dc60406808a4da/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rel/registrar.py", line 179, in callback
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991898687Z     self.events\[etype\]\[fd\].callback()
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991902887Z   File "/tmp/8dc60406808a4da/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rel/listener.py", line 127, in callback
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991907287Z     if not self.cb(\*self.args) and not self.persist and self.active:
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991924987Z            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991929087Z   File "/tmp/8dc60406808a4da/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/websocket/\_app.py", line 515, in read
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991933287Z     op_code, frame = self.sock.recv_data_frame(True)
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991936687Z                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991940587Z   File "/tmp/8dc60406808a4da/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/websocket/\_core.py", line 461, in recv_data_frame
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991944587Z     self.pong(frame.data)
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991948187Z   File "/tmp/8dc60406808a4da/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/websocket/\_core.py", line 377, in pong
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991952087Z     self.send(payload, ABNF.OPCODE_PONG)
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991957087Z   File "/tmp/8dc60406808a4da/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/websocket/\_core.py", line 297, in send
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991960987Z     return self.send_frame(frame)
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991964487Z            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991967987Z   File "/tmp/8dc60406808a4da/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/websocket/\_core.py", line 337, in send_frame
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991971787Z     l = self.\_send(data)
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991975087Z         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-27T09:59:19.991978787Z   File "/tmp/8dc60406808a4da/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/websocket/\_core.py", line 559, in \_send
2024-04-27T09:59:19.992036988Z     return send(self.sock, data)
2024-04-27T09:59:19.992043088Z            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-27T09:59:19.992047388Z   File "/tmp/8dc60406808a4da/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/websocket/\_socket.py", line 176, in send
2024-04-27T09:59:19.992051988Z     return \_send()
2024-04-27T09:59:19.992056188Z            ^^^^^^^
2024-04-27T09:59:19.992060688Z   File "/tmp/8dc60406808a4da/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/websocket/\_socket.py", line 153, in \_send
2024-04-27T09:59:19.992065088Z     return sock.send(data)
2024-04-27T09:59:19.992069088Z            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-27T09:59:19.992073088Z   File "/opt/python/3.11.7/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 1243, in send
2024-04-27T09:59:19.998976055Z     return self.\_sslobj.write(data)
2024-04-27T09:59:19.998993255Z            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-04-27T09:59:19.998998955Z ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (\_ssl.c:2427)

The process restarts and app keeps running until another exception appears. I have a feeling that i am missing some configuration in Azure. App is configured to be "Always on"
Full app configuration:
enter image description here
tryed everything i could google on this topic with no luck

if possible, can you share your github repo?

Unfortunately, this is a closed repo

Are you deploying the app via GitHub, DevOps, or the Visual Studio extension?


ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2427)

To avoid above error message,
Ensure that you are using the latest versions of libraries.
Make sure there are no timeout settings in your code or Azure environment that might be closing the connection prematurely.
I successfully deployed a simple Flask app to Azure App Service without any issues.
app .py
from flask import Flask
import multiprocessing
app = Flask(__name__)
process = None
queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
latestQueueData = ""
def do_binance_trading(queue): 
    print("Going to start a socket. . .")
    print("Socket started. . .")
@app.route("/") 
def main(): 
    global process
    global queue
    global latestQueueData 
    print("Ping app. . .")
    if process is not None and process.is_alive():
        print("App is running. Trading process id:" + str(process.pid))           
        queue_data = []
        while not queue.empty():
            queue_data.append(queue.get())
        if len(queue_data) > 0 and latestQueueData != queue_data[-1]:
            latestQueueData = queue_data[-1]   
        return latestQueueData.replace("\n", "<br>"), 200
    else:
        print("Starting App. . .")
        queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_binance_trading, args=(queue,))
        process.start()
        print("Process started. . .")
        return "Trading started", 200
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app.run()

Local output:

I deployed the app via visual studio code extension


Output after deployment:

Logstream :

App configuration :


Surprisingly, I am running kind of the same exact code for over a week without any issues.
Also, I use exact same deployment pipeline.
Finally, the mentioned issue didn't appear after the deployment. But some time after it. My be in 4h, may be more

Sometimes, limited memory or CPU resources can cause this issue. Make sure your Azure App Service plan has enough resources for your application. Try to upscale your azure app service plan.
